# C# - Why is Math.Atan(1) != anything near 45

Tags: c#, math

There is another post here about Atan but I dont see any relevant answers:

[C# - Why Math.Atan(Math.Tan(x)) != x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311501/c-why-math-atanmath-tanx-x)

Isn't Math.Atan the same as tan-1? On my calculator I do:

> tan-1(1) and i get 45.
>
> tan(45) = 1

In C#:

> Math.Atan(1) = 0.78539816339744828 //
>   nowhere near the 45.
>
> Math.Tan(45) = 1.6197751905438615 //1
>   dp over the < Piover2.

Whats happening here?

Comment: Are both results in same units, like degrees or radians?

Comment: I asked my math teacher this same question 25 years ago, except of course I was asking about BASIC on the Commodore PET, not about C#. :)

Comment: On my calculators I can switch between degrees, radians and grads.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

C# is treating the angles as radians; your calculator is using degrees.

Answer (score 24):

`Atan(1)` is equal to π/4. This is the correct value when working in radians. The same can be said of the other calculations in the library.

Feel free to convert the values:

```
double DegreeToRadian(double angle) { return Math.PI * angle / 180.0;   }
double RadianToDegree(double angle) { return angle * (180.0 / Math.PI); }
```

This means that 45 radians is equal to about 2578.31008 degrees, so the tangent you are looking for should be better expressed as tan(π/4) or if you don't mind "cheating": `Math.Tan(Math.Atan(1)); // ~= 1`. I'm fairly confident that had you tried that yourself, you'd have realized something reasonable was happening, and might have stumbled upon how radians relate to degrees.

Comment: So ... Following how you use the words, shouldn't the methods be named DegreesToRadians() and RadiansToDegrees()?

Comment: Sure. Call them whatever you want. `d2r()` and `r2d()` might make fun macro names if C# supported macros.

Answer (score 8):

Your calculator is in Degrees, C# is doing these calculations in Radians.

To get the correct values:

```
int angle = 45;  //in degrees

int result = Math.Tan(45 * Math.PI/180);

int aTanResult = Math.Atan(result) *180/Math.PI;
```

Answer (score 3):

Math.Atan returns a value in radians.  Your calculator is using degrees.  0.7853... (pi/4) radians is 45 degrees.  (And conversely Math.Tan(45) is telling you the tan of 45 radians.)