# C# Math.Cos(double) returns wrong value

Tags: c#

In C# I have this:

```
double Cos = Math.Cos(32.471192290848492); //Equals 0.49299653250335213
```

But when I do this in a calculator I get this

```
(0.84366148773210745476752872050588)
```

Why is it returning the wrong value?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1564207/1071834.  Perhaps these should be merged and the question and answer expanded to cover all the major trig operations to avoid future duplicates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Why is Math.Atan(1) != anything near 45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564207/c-sharp-why-is-math-atan1-anything-near-45)

Answer (score 20):

Math.Cos is expecting an angle *in radians*.  I suspect your calculator is working in degrees.

You should be able to get the same answer by converting the value in degrees to radians:

```
double angleInDegrees = 32.471192290848492;
double cos = Math.Cos(angleInDegrees * (Math.PI / 180.0));
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.
I get 0.49 in C#.
And I get 0.84 in windows calculator.

Comment: @Matt Try again, this is the problem (and Reed's code works.)

Answer (score 6):

You're probably confusing degrees with radians.  Most calculators use Degrees, whereas most programming languages are set up to use radians.

Answer (score 4):

Because `Math.Cos` works in *radians* and your calculator in *degrees*.