# Why is the .Net Math.Cos function giving me a different answer than the calculator?

Tags: c#, .net, math

I'm so confused and I thought my program was written incorrectly, but now I realized where the problem is.

I'm getting two different values for the Cosine of a number.

For example for this number 329.85

on a calculator I get 0.8647.....

in my C# program I get -0.99985159087810649
using this expression

```
double asnwer = Math.Cos(329.85);
```

Can someone please explain what is going on?  Or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Math.Cos(double) returns wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166034/c-sharp-math-cosdouble-returns-wrong-value)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C# and the .NET Framework the trigonometric math methods are meant for radians.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos(v=vs.110).aspx

I would recommend creating a method for converting degrees to radians as follows:

```
double DegreesToRadians(double degrees)
{
   return degrees * Math.PI / 180.0;
}
```

Then just try out the following:

```
Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(329.85));
```

Comment: OMG thanks so much.  I just assumed it would behave exactly like my calculator.  Totally forgot about degrees and radians.

Answer (score 6):

Your calculator is using degrees (although it might have a radians mode too), whereas `Math.Cos` in C# expects radians.

Try: `Math.Cos(329.85*2*Math.PI/360)`

Answer (score -3):

Your calculator is assuming radians.  .NET is degrees.

Comment: This is exactly backwards.